# How to modify the command line text showing in Mac terminal

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, bash

My Macbook Pro shows a wired string ("**ryoitasuou**") at terminal like below picture.

Does any know how to remove or modify it ?

I already deleted the "**ryoitasuou**" folder in /Users folder , and modify username in "bash_profile" , but these steps does not help.

p.s. I bought this Macbook Pro 2019 from Amazon , and the wired name is already exist after I finished user setup at the first time I boot up this laptop.
This is really annoying every time I use Terminal.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you need to change the account name; see Apple's support document [HT201548: "Change the name of your macOS user account and home folder"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548). **Be sure to create a second admin account** to do the change from. Changing the account name will remove your admin rights, and without a second admin account to re-grant them, getting them back is a pain (see ["Changing my administrator user's username has removed privileges"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304640/changing-my-administrator-users-username-has-removed-privileges)).

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem by creating another user and delete the original one , I have not idea why I can not change the user name of my first user account.

Answer (score -1):

Bash performs a lookup in /etc/passwd, well on macOS it looks in opendirectory, for the users HOME folder at every invocation. Try the following-

```
 dscl . -read /Users/$(id -un) NFSHomeDirectory RecordName
```

You will need to change the NFSHomeDirectory value and more than likely the RecordName in opendirectory.

Comment: At least a *HINT* of how to change that value would be an appropriate part of the solution