# How to change system username via terminal

Tags: terminal, user-account, accounts

Generally speaking, I have `localadmin`, which is an `Administrator` account, and I have X more `Standard` accounts. What I want to do, from this `localadmin` account, is change system usernames for other accounts via terminal.

Normally, this procedure would look like as if you went to **System Preferences > Users & Groups** and manually changed the username for those accounts.

Anyway, if you want to change username, then you will need this *third-party admin account*, since you are not able to change system username being on the account for what you want to change.

So, how can I change system username via terminal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a "third-party admin account"?

Comment: Just admin account from which you will be changing username since it's impossible to change username of account being logged in to that account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the user with username `user` whose home folder is at `/Users/user` to `user2` run

```
dscl . change /Users/user RecordName user user2
```

This doesn't change the user's home folder.

Comment: Note that the user will lose any group memberships (other than the "staff" group), because those are tracked by name. Most importantly, if they were an administrator (i.e. a member of the "admin" group) before the name change, they won't be under the new name. See ["Changing my administrator user's username has removed privileges "](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304640/changing-my-administrator-users-username-has-removed-privileges).